# How to capture CodeMirror hide/unhide events?

Tags: codemirror

I want to capture events when markers are removed or when the remove is undone. The docs say there are "hide" and "unhide" events but I can't figure out how to capture these events. Can anyone provide a code snippet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out:

```
// Create a marker
var myMark = cm.markText(...)

// Add the listener directly on the marker
CodeMirror.on(myMark, "hide", function(){
    // do stuff
});
```